# If page is a taxonomy do X, if is a term, do Y

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I am having an issue with a template for a site, I need to be able to check if the page is a taxonomy archive or is a term page

My code:

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), 'catalog');
if(is_tax( 'catalog' ) && $term->parent == 0) {
 // code  
} elseif($term->parent > 0) {
 // code
}
```

The code currently works in that it displays the first piece of code on the taxonomy, and the second part displays it on a term which has children, but I need the second part of the code to display on all term pages.

I have tried using has_term but not been successful, can anyone point me in the right direction on how to show different code for a taxonomy and for a term.

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Could you use the template hierarchy rather than an if/else statement? http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Comment: it's in a template file (taxonomy-slug.php), I can't a term template as there are in the region of 200 terms

Comment: a taxonomy archive is a term archive, there aren't "taxonomy archives" and "term pages", they are one and the same.

Comment: Agree with Milo. On taxonomy-slug.php you're showing an archive of the posts associated with one term in that taxonomy (that's what you're identifying in get_query_var('term')). So I guess I'm not understanding what you need. What "taxonomy" specific info do you need to display, vs "term" specific info?

Comment: The client is going to create the taxonomy-slug-term.php files as it's the easiest way (although a pain in the butt). The tax archive displays a list of all the terms with their children, the term displays all the products for the term. We have sorted it now though.

Comment: it's still not clear what problem you were trying to solve, so it's difficult to give you an answer that isn't a "pain in the butt". it likely involves a [template filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy) though. you say "The tax archive displays a list of all the terms with their children", which isn't a view that WordPress generates - all templates output groups of posts, there is no concept of a term list view.